# FindBugs sequence of calls to ConcurrentHashMap may not be atomic

Tags: java, findbugs

I do not understand why FindBug complains about this code

```
Foo obj = map.get(id);

if(obj == null) {
    obj = new Foo();
    map.put(id, obj);
}

obj.add(someObject);
```

Second Version

```
Foo tmp = new Foo();
obj = map.putIfAbsent(id, tmp);
if (obj == null)
   obj = tmp

obj.add(someObject);
```

If I do second version, I have to create `Foo` object every time.

```
Foo obj = map.get(id);

if(obj == null) {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    try {
        obj = new Foo();
        map.put(id, obj);
    }finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}

obj.add(someObject);
```

With third version, FindBugs still complains about not atomic.

It says :

> Sequence of calls to concurrenthashmap may not be atomic

Changing put to `putIfAbsent`, FindBugs still complains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Findbugs observes that the pair of method invocations `map.get(id)`, `map.put(id, obj)` may not be atomic, meaning that it is possible that some other thread modifies `map` in between.

For example, another thread may record a different mapping for key `id` between those two calls, which then gets silently lost when the first thread executes its `map.put()`.  Since you bother to test whether there is initially a mapping for that key, this result seems unlikely to be an acceptable one.

One way to approach this issue would be to use `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent()` in place of *both* calls (not just in place of `put()`).

Comment: Updated my code with what you have suggested, but I do not want create foo object every time

Comment: If you need to be able to perform an atomic sequence of multiple operations on your map, then everywhere the map is touched, access must be appropriately synchronized on a common object.  That common object could be the map itself, but does not need to be.  If you are going to do that then `ConcurrentHashMap` does not do anything useful for you; in that case you should switch to an ordinary `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

If some other thread adds an entry with that key while your thread is evaluating the `if ()` statement, your thread will overwrite it.

You need to use `putIfAbsent` **only**, not not interact with the map otherwise.

Comment: Updated my code, suggest how I can avoid creating the foo object everytime and still make code look good